# Запретить использование зарезервированных имен в консоли

Tags: c++, файлы

Программа открывает текстовый файл, как исключить ввод всех зарезервированных слов в Windows?

```
string filename;
cout << "Введите путь к файлу: ";
cin >> filename;
ifstream file(filename);
```

Если ввести например `con`, то программа повиснет на 4 строке.

Comment: ну так добавьте проверку вида `if (filename == "con") { cout << "ups"; return 1; }`

Comment: Не верю что программа "висит" именно на этой строчке. Скорее всего, она "висит" дальше, где вы читаете этот файл.

Comment: используйте `std::set<std::string>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть последний компилятор, то можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    string filename;
    cout << "Введите путь к файлу: ";
    cin >> filename;
    if (!is_regular_file(filename))
    {
        cout << "Not a regular file!";
        return 1;
    }
    // Дальше как обычно
    ifstream file(filename);
}
```

Таким образом, даже если ifstream откроет con, то до этого мы узнаем, что это не является обычным файлом, из которого можно читать.

Comment: Этот метод не занимается проверкой наличия в пути зарезервированных символов, он только проверят что по указанному пути имеется обычный файл. Например `assert(is_regular_file("test.txt"));` выдаст ошибку, хотя путь не содержит ничего запрещенного.

Comment: Это само собой, подразумевается, что автор уже сделал проверку на наличие файла. Например, с помощью std::experimental::filesystem::exists

Comment: Так вопрос заключается в проверке наличия в пути зарезервированных символов. Другими словами, проверка должна работать даже если такого файла еще нет и мы только собираемся его создать.

Comment: @CarbonBasedLifeform, данный способ будет работать на C# ?